# Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications [Codemagic]

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

Since I updated my flutter project to v2 I'm getting this error on Codemagic and I don't know what to do honestly.

I'm using Windows 10 to develop on Flutter and Codemagic to compile to iOS, until the update (v2) everything was fine...

This is what I get on codemagic.io build error:

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-09 10:18:40.585 xcodebuild[2615:21289] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-09 10:18:40.585 xcodebuild[2615:21289] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.xXPcDy/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirEKd7Sr/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework Reachability'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
        note: Target 'Reachability' (in project 'Pods')
        note: Target 'ReachabilitySwift' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'
        note: Target 'Reachability' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'
        note: Target 'ReachabilitySwift' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: unexpected mutating task ('SetOwnerAndGroup builder:staff /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetOwnerAndGroup builder:staff /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework') (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: unexpected mutating task ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework') (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' on task: Copy /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Modules/module.modulemap /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/ReachabilitySwift.build/module.modulemap (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Reachability' on task: CreateUniversalBinary /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Reachability normal arm64 armv7 (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: CreateUniversalBinary /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Reachability normal arm64 armv7 (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework' on task: MkDir /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: MkDir /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Headers' on task: MkDir /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Headers (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: MkDir /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Headers (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework/Info.plist /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/ReachabilitySwift/ReachabilitySwift-Info.plist (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: SetOwnerAndGroup builder:staff /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: SetOwnerAndGroup builder:staff /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '' on task: Touch /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.xXPcDy/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirEKd7Sr/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'

Encountered error while archiving for device.


Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

Any idea of how to fix this without a MAC OS?

Codemagic Build Settings:

```
Flutter version: 2.10.5
Xcode version: 13.3.1 (i tried with multiple versions already)
CocoaPods version: 1.11.3
```

Comment: Managed to fix the error by deleting deprecated Dependencies that used network managing like for example connectivity: ^3.0.6 from pubspec.yaml

Flutter clean 
and Flutter pub get 
and problem solved.

Comment: please add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the error by deleting deprecated Dependencies that used network managing for example connectivity: ^3.0.6 from pubspec.yaml.

After cleaning those deprecated Dependencies do
**Flutter clean** and **Flutter pub get** and problem solved.

flutter pub upgrade also helps a lot when it comes to deprecated Dependencies.. keep in mind that some dependencies might not work as they might be too old.. in that case, you will have to find some new dependence doing the same job.